# Replace a line feed in SQL with TRANSLATE

Tags: sql, oracle, linefeed

Apparently Oracle appends a line feed character `CHR(10)` to the end of the default value when it stores it in the system catalogue.

I'm trying to replace a line feed in some SQL report data using the `TRANSLATE` function but I'm unsure of the syntax. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Syntax is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html). Bookmark it.

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour. Can you share an example? What is the "system catalog"? Why `translate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate? If you're trying to *replace* it, then do so.

```
select replace(some_value, chr(10), null) from ...
```

which replaces `chr(10)` with `null`.